# TestFlight - No users in build permission list

Tags: ios, testing, testflight

I'm trying to deploy my app for testing via TestFlight. I've invited 2 other people to the team I've created and added them to a distribution list, yet the app does not show up for downloading to them, it does for me.

When I go to the build permission screen on the site this is what I see:

[image]

Only I show up on the permission list even though there are 3 people in both of the distribution lists. Any idea what's happening here?

**EDIT:** this is what is seen in the people tab:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you added their UDID's to the provisioning profile, rebuilt the app, and uploaded a version that includes their UDIDs?  From the [TestFlight FAQ](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402851-testflight-faq):

> For a Developer Sign up with TestFlight and create your team. Invite
>   and gather the UDIDs from the team members and add them to your Apple
>   Developer Portal and provisioning profile for the app. Build the
>   IPhone Application (.IPA) and upload to TestFlight. Distribute the
>   build to team members and let the magic happen. Receive feedback,
>   monitor tester's activity and perform a full fledge beta test from the
>   comfort of your chair. Developers on teams can also upload multiple
>   apps for testing/internal distribution.

Here's a definitive way to verify that their UDID is in the IPA:

- unzip the .ipa
- look at Payload/*appname*/embedded.mobileprovision
- look in the "ProvisionedDevices" array

If their UDID is not there, you need to check your provisioning profile and rebuild your app/ipa.  TestFlight looks in the IPA to determine who is provisioned for any particular build.

Comment: I invited them via email and they registered with the app and their devices appear in the group, I'll update with another picture.